# Can we set one database between Java and python?

Tags: java, python, mysql, database, database-connection

I created python script that sends notifications when result declared but I want to make website that takes data of student email id and store in database.

Now here problem is that I don't know django framework so it takes time to make website.
Java, database connection, Data insertion,
Servelet calling easily do that by me.

Want to know way that java html css takes input from user and stores in database and then python program retrieves that data.

Hope you understand my question.

Comment: The short answer is "YES".  However, the question is too broad for StackOverflow. Please visit the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: This is mostly specific to your application domain. 
But yes. we can use java setup as a mere ORM tool and python for all the processing.

Answer (score 0):

If you know python, I think `Django` might be a good choice for you. Django itself attempts to support as many features as possible on the backend. You only need to configure the database parameters in settings.py and Django ORM can automate the transfer  of data stored in tables into objects. You don't have to implement the features yourself and it saves you tons of time.

Django has its own ModelForm class. It maps to the Models(eg. Student), it is quite easy to submit your `Student` info and store it in db.

```
# settings.py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'read_default_file': '/path/to/my.cnf',
        },
    }
}


# my.cnf
[client]
database = NAME
user = USER
password = PASSWORD
default-character-set = utf8
```

If you insist using Java to implement the database backend, for sure you can share it with python. Some choices like JDBC, Hibernate and Mybatis.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can share the DB, you'll have to install the corresponding dependencies for connecting python to the DB as well as for Java. I've done this with postgresql, mysql and mssql